# In C, how to change a local scope variable without a pointer?

Tags: c

The ncurses library has a functions that change local scope variables without any pointers. For example:

```
int x, y;
getyx(stdscr, y, x);    //to get the current position of the cursor
```

How does this happen?

Comment: It’s a macro, not a function.

Comment: How is getyx declared?

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit — presuming you're referring to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105361/in-c-how-to-change-a-local-scope-variable-without-a-pointer#comment98844693_56105361), it _is_ a comment, though it does contain the core information for an answer.  It doesn't have the desirable support (links to the documentation) that your answer provides, so it isn't, as it stands, suitable as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`getyx` is not a function, but a macro.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getyx)

<sup>(Ignore the very confusing `void` return type on that manpage; the prose underneath tells us the truth!)</sup>

> #### Notes
>
> All of these interfaces are macros. A "`&`" is not necessary before the variables `y` and `x`.

It does not introduce or use a new scope, so has direct "access" to `x` and `y` as they are.

As an analogy, consider how the following works without a `&`:

```
#define doubleIt(x) x *= 2

int main()
{
   int x = 1;
   doubleIt(x);
}
```

Comment: @P__J__ Agreed! Although it's not as bad in C++ (where you already have to be on the lookout for reference parameters) than it was in C (where this is really quite surprising to read)